# How to checked or unchecked all parent and child nodes separately by button click

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a tree view that has some parent nodes and child nodes.I have four buttons. In which two buttons are of checked and unchecked only parent nodes and two buttons are of child nodes.
I want checked only parent nodes if i click `btnAllParentChecked` and unchecked if i click `btnAllparentUnchecked` and similarly for child nodes.I have done some code for child nodes.

```
Boolean bChildTrigger = true;
        Boolean bParentTrigger = true;
        private void CheckAllChildren(TreeNodeCollection trNodeCollection, Boolean bCheck)
        {
            bParentTrigger = false;
            foreach (TreeNode ctn in trNodeCollection)
            {
                bChildTrigger = false;
                ctn.Checked = bCheck;
                bChildTrigger = true;

                CheckAllChildren(ctn.Nodes, bCheck);
            }
            bParentTrigger = true;
        }

 private void btnAllPropertyChecked_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CheckAllChildren(treSelector.Nodes, true);
        }

private void btnAllPropertyUnChecked_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CheckAllChildren(treSelector.Nodes, false);
        }
```

How can i implement this functionality in treeview?

Comment: [Have you tried anything](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? Questions that doesn't show what the user has tried, usually gets closed.

Comment: Show your HTML markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all you need. Tested and works well

```
private void ChangeNodesSelection(TreeNodeCollection node,bool doCheck)
    {
        foreach (TreeNode n in node)
        {
            n.Checked = doCheck;
            if (n.Nodes.Count > 0)
            {
                ChangeNodesSelection(n.Nodes,doCheck);
            }
        }
    }

private void UncheckParentNodes(TreeNodeCollection node)
    {
        foreach (TreeNode n in node)
        {
            if (n.Parent == null && n.Nodes.Count == 0)
                n.Checked = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have use this but same thing is happening.Parent node get selected which have no child node.

Comment: you don't want to select the node which has no child nodes?

Comment: Yes, I dont want to select the node which has no child node.

Comment: I have added another method. Call that after calling the first one. You can call like this ChangeNodesSelection(treeView1.Nodes, true);
            UncheckParentNodes(treeView1.Nodes);